# How to find out if a client connection is terminated within a TCP socket connection in a java server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, tcp

I'm implementing a multithreaded server using blocking read/write on TCP sockets with InputStream and OutputStream primitives wrapped-up by appropriate Reader/Writer.

The `InputStreamReader's read()` method returns `-1` if the client is disconnected but it keeps waiting indefinitely if the client connection is intact. How do I overcome this?

Comment: "Client connection lost within a TCP socket connection" is meaningless. Unclear what you're asking, unless what you're looking for is a socket read timeout.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. In my case, the client has a timeout on its side after which the operation terminates. The ruby client has a Timeout::timeout wrapped around this function call.

Comment: So what's your question? The timout trips -> something is wrong. Could be network or slow server or a few other things, but that's the only mechanism you have available.

Comment: NB "connection is terminated within a TCP connection' is also meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The most important question here is what does "is lost" really mean for the application. There are two roles in a socket communication - a writer and a reader. Our code may play both of the roles at the same time. So, for a socket communication:

1. From the writer's point of view, the connection "is lost" means the writer gets an error while write/send to the socket (`OutputStream.write(...)`). For TCP this happens only due to receiving FIN or RST, or due to retransmission timeout (isn't available in Java to be managed) or due to OS has detected the connection is lost with TCP keepalive (https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)
2. From the reader's point of view, the connection "is lost" means the reader gets an error while read from the socket (`InputStream.read(...)`). For TCP this happens only due to to receiving FIN or RST, or due to OS has detected "lost" connection with TCP keepalive, or due to blocking read timeout (SO_TIMEOUT).

Both TCP retransmission timeout (RTO) and TCP keepalive work not so good:

1. RTO: https://pracucci.com/linux-tcp-rto-min-max-and-tcp-retries2.html
2. Keepalive is even worst: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-keepalive. By default Windows sends the first TCP Keepalive packet after 2 hours(!). The same issue on Linux https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

So, if you are a server, I'd strongly recommend to just use forcibly set SO_TIMEOUT (or your own equivalent for unblocking read), OR to introduce health/availability-checking on the application's level. There are two typical patterns: a ping-pong (after a timeout is reached, the server sends a ping packet to a client and awaits for a pong received back), a heartbeat (the client should send a heartbeat package in a specified period of time). Note, that often the client experiences the same problem and you may decide to support ping-pong/heartbeat for both sides.

Just an interesting post on the topic https://blog.cloudflare.com/when-tcp-sockets-refuse-to-die/

Answer (score -1):

Are you creating the Input stream over a socket object?

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = server.accept();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Then you can check if socket is connected using

```
socket.isClosed()
```

in between your loops?

Comment: You seem to ascribe magical properties to `isClosed()`. It doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It is initally false, and becomes true when *you* close the socket, and at no other time: specifically, it doesn't magically become true when the *peer* disconnects or the connection is aborted. And in case you want to substitute `isConnected()`, that won't work either, for cognate reasons. You haven't tried this.